# Problema al cargar una cadena con mucha informacion en javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

Creo una conexion a una base de datos mysql en php y cargo una variable con informacion de un campo de una tabla de la bd, mi problema es que al cargar mucha información no puedo trabajar con esta variable utilizando javascript

```
include("Conexion.php");

$rs = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM tbl_publicacion WHERE publicacion_id = $publicacion_id");

while($datos = mysqli_fetch_array($rs)){
    $descripcion = $datos['publicacion_descripcion'];
}
```

Luego en un bloque script tengo esto:

```
var descripcion = "<?php echo $descripcion; ?>";
            alert(descripcion);
```

Si en el campo de la tabla tengo poca informacion si me muestra la variable en el alert, pero si tengo demasiada informacion esta variable no se puede trabajar con javascript, no me muestra nunca el alert y al llamar esta variable en una funcion esta funcion no se llama nunca...

¿Que puedo hacer para cargar una variable con la cantidad de informacion que yo quiera y trabajarla con javascript?

> Aclarando: la variable con la informacion en **php** si carga los datos sin importar el tamaño del texto. al mostrarla con echo me muestra los datos perfectamente.
>   El problema es solo por javascript...

Comment: Me entra la duda: en tu while, $descripcion tiene un "=", o sea que se sobre escribe en cada iteración, ¿es así como lo quieres? si no, $descripcion siempre tendrá el último valor asignado en el while, o sea el último registro de la consulta. Dices que no te imprime nada, ¿Cuántos caracteres tiene cuando sucede eso?

Comment: 1) En la consulta le tengo que me traiga de la tabla el campo solo cuando encuentre 1 id, este id es unico asi que no sobreescribo informacion. 2) Ahi un problema con la cantidad de caracteres que soporta javascript?

Comment: Esque la informacion que traigo varia dependiendo del vinculo a que le de click, aveces trae poca informacion y aveces trae bastante, lo que estoy trayendo es toda una pagina sin incluir la estructura html. solo el contenido del body.

Comment: Ah ok, vale. De lo segundo que preguntas, las variables de todos los lenguajes tienen un límite de almacenamiento. En tu caso concreto, debe ser un valor muy grande, desconozco si el *alert* tenga un límite. Te sugiero que en vez de alert, hagas un console.log para que si te imprime. Quizá $descripcion en vez de contener un string, contenga un array o algo diferente a un string, eso puede causar que no funcione

Comment: Caray, lo último que dices suena a mala idea :v

Comment: Probaste simplemente `alert("<?php echo $descripcion; ?>");` para saltarte ese límite de tamaño de las variables?

Comment: Si lo probe pero da lo mismo, al final lo que hice fue que enves de imprimir por JavaScript la variable descripcion lo hice mediante un echo de PhP y me funciono perfectamente, nunca pude resolver lo de JavaScript.

Comment: Y como mantienes el formato? Como harías para que el campo de la tabla mantenga el formato en el html cuando este dato actualice el textarea?

Answer (score 1):

no creo que tu problema sea que el tamaño de tu cadena tenga mucha información, puede ser que como en la cadena guardas una descripcion en texto, este pueda contener saltos de linea (\n), al pasar esta variable de php a js con echo por ejemplo, este salto de linea aparece causandote error.

si en php tienes el codigo:

```
<?php $descripcion="texto largo...\n...mas texto"; ?>
```

y en el js haces esto:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> alert('<?php echo $descripcion ?>');</script>
```

en el navegador aparecerá:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> alert('texto largo...
...mas texto');</script>
```

y por esta razón no se ejecutará el alert. Puedes verificar esto haciendo ctrl+U para ver el código en tu navegador.

Para deshacerte de los saltos de linea en tu variable puedes utilizar el siguiente código en php:

```
$nueva_descripcion=str_ireplace("\n",' ',$descripcion);
```

Este código remplazará los saltos de linea con espacios.
En caso de que no te sea familiar el termino salto de linea, este se da cuando presionas "Enter" al escribir en un textarea por ejemplo, este "Enter" se guarda como un carácter para que se mantengan los parrafos de un texto.

Espero sea de ayuda. saludos.